# Open Source Image Software

Tags: image

I need an open source disk imaging application (something like Ghost or Acronis). Which one would you suggest?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I like GParted and CloneZilla. GParted is my favorite for single-use, CloneZilla's best when you need to blast images out across the network.

Answer (score 5):

[dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) and [dd_rescue](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/).

See also, this question: [Using DD for disk cloning](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning)

Comment: The advantage of dd is that is available on almost every linux environment, including that old Ubuntu DVD you got in a magazine once. If you learn how to use the dd + netcat + gzip combo you'll have a very flexible tool in your mental toolbox for network imaging

Answer (score 3):

My personal choice is [PING (Partimage Is Not Ghost)](http://ping.windowsdream.com/) as I've used it considerably at work and at home, with much success. We've got base images for our most common machine models. 1.5 - 2 Hour builds down to 25-30mins depending on the machine.

So far I've only tried backing up to another partition or a USB drive, though it does support backing up to a network drive.

Answer (score 3):

I like [g4u](http://www.feyrer.de/g4u/) and [FOG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeghost/).

- g4u is more of a standalone system for single (or just a few) machines.
- FOG is really a complete replacement for a ghost system and is really intended for large environments.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about [FOG](http://www.fogproject.org/) as a Ghost alternative. No personal experience to back that up, however, as I used a custom PXE solution before FOG was available.

Comment: Floss weekly has done a podcast on FOG. http://twit.tv/floss53

Answer (score 2):

I use dd. =D

Answer (score 1):

Designed more for backups than cloning, but **mondo** is pretty good.

It creates bootable ISO's of your hard drive, from which you can easily restore to a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

it is not opensource but in a pinch, maxblast is very good.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitively not "open source", but maybe still good enough and has an API:
Imagex / WIM files from the Windows Vista AIK toolkit. With that free download you get Windows PE and the imagex command line tool. It will make a file based image of your ntfs drive into a WIM-file which is single instance, compressed and stores everything you need (ACLs, owner, streams) and only skips pagefile if you want.

It's very easy to use, e.g. over a mounted network share!