# Does the "bs" option in "dd" really improve the speed?

Tags: linux, kernel, dd, disk-image

Every now and then, I'm told that to increase the speed of a "dd" I should carefully choose a proper "block size".

Even here, on ServerFault, someone else [wrote](https://serverfault.com/questions/147935/how-to-determine-the-best-byte-size-for-the-dd-command) that "*...the optimum block size is hardware dependent...*" [(iain)](https://serverfault.com/users/9517/iain) or "*...the perfect size will depend on your system bus, hard drive controller, the particular drive itself, and the drivers for each of those...*" [(chris-s)](https://serverfault.com/users/33417/chris-s)

As my feeling was a bit different (*BTW: I tought that the time needed to deeply-tune the bs parameter was much higher than the gain received, in terms of time-saved, and that the default was reasonable*), today I just went through some quick-and-dirty benchmarks.

In order to lower external influences, I decided to read:

- from an external MMC card
- from an internal partition

and:

- with related filesystems umounted
- sending the output to /dev/null to avoid issues related to "writing speed";
- avoiding some basic issues of HDD-caching, at least when involving the HDD.

In the following table, I've reported my findings, reading 1GB of data with different values of "bs" (*you can find the raw numbers at the end of this message*):

[image]

Basically it cames out that:

- MMC: with a bs=4 (yes! 4 bytes), I reached a throughput of 12MB/s. A not so distant values wrt to the maximum 14.2/14.3 that I got from bs=5 and above;
- HDD: with a bs=10 I reached 30 MB/s. Surely lower than the 95.3 MB got with the default bs=512 but... significant as well.

Also, it was very clear that the CPU sys-time was inversely proportional to the bs value (but this sounds reasonable, as the lower the bs, the higher the number of sys-calls generated by dd).

Having said all the above, now the question: can someone explain (a kernel hacker?) what are the major component/systems involved in such throughput, and if it really worth the effort in specifying a bs higher than the default?

---

### MMC case - raw numbers

#### bs=1M

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1000
1000+0 record dentro
1000+0 record fuori
1048576000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 74,1239 s, 14,1 MB/s

real    1m14.126s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m1.588s
```

#### bs=1k

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null bs=1k count=1000000
1000000+0 record dentro
1000000+0 record fuori
1024000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 72,7795 s, 14,1 MB/s

real    1m12.782s
user    0m0.244s
sys     0m2.092s
```

#### bs=512

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null bs=512 count=2000000
2000000+0 record dentro
2000000+0 record fuori
1024000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 72,867 s, 14,1 MB/s

real    1m12.869s
user    0m0.324s
sys     0m2.620s
```

#### bs=10

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null bs=10 count=100000000
100000000+0 record dentro
100000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 70,1662 s, 14,3 MB/s

real    1m10.169s
user    0m6.272s
sys     0m28.712s
```

#### bs=5

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null bs=5 count=200000000
200000000+0 record dentro
200000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 70,415 s, 14,2 MB/s

real    1m10.417s
user    0m11.604s
sys     0m55.984s
```

#### bs=4

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null bs=4 count=250000000
250000000+0 record dentro
250000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 80,9114 s, 12,4 MB/s

real    1m20.914s
user    0m14.436s
sys     1m6.236s
```

#### bs=2

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null bs=2 count=500000000
500000000+0 record dentro
500000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 161,974 s, 6,2 MB/s

real    2m41.976s
user    0m28.220s
sys     2m13.292s
```

#### bs=1

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null bs=1 count=1000000000
1000000000+0 record dentro
1000000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 325,316 s, 3,1 MB/s

real    5m25.318s
user    0m56.212s
sys     4m28.176s
```

---

### HDD case - raw numbers

#### bs=1

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/null bs=1 count=1000000000
1000000000+0 record dentro
1000000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 341,461 s, 2,9 MB/s

real    5m41.463s
user    0m56.000s
sys 4m44.340s
```

#### bs=2

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/null bs=2 count=500000000
500000000+0 record dentro
500000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 164,072 s, 6,1 MB/s

real    2m44.074s
user    0m28.584s
sys 2m14.628s
```

#### bs=4

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/null bs=4 count=250000000
250000000+0 record dentro
250000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 81,471 s, 12,3 MB/s

real    1m21.473s
user    0m14.824s
sys 1m6.416s
```

#### bs=5

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/null bs=5 count=200000000
200000000+0 record dentro
200000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 66,0327 s, 15,1 MB/s

real    1m6.035s
user    0m11.176s
sys 0m54.668s
```

#### bs=10

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/null bs=10 count=100000000
100000000+0 record dentro
100000000+0 record fuori
1000000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 33,4151 s, 29,9 MB/s

real    0m33.417s
user    0m5.692s
sys 0m27.624s
```

#### bs=512 (offsetting the read, to avoid caching)

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/null bs=512 count=2000000 skip=6000000
2000000+0 record dentro
2000000+0 record fuori
1024000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 10,7437 s, 95,3 MB/s

real    0m10.746s
user    0m0.360s
sys 0m2.428s
```

#### bs=1k (offsetting the read, to avoid caching)

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/null bs=1k count=1000000 skip=6000000
1000000+0 record dentro
1000000+0 record fuori
1024000000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 10,6561 s, 96,1 MB/s

real    0m10.658s
user    0m0.164s
sys 0m1.772s
```

#### bs=1k (offsetting the read, to avoid caching)

```
root@iMac-Chiara:/tmp# time dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1000 skip=7000
1000+0 record dentro
1000+0 record fuori
1048576000 byte (1,0 GB) copiati, 10,7391 s, 97,6 MB/s

real    0m10.792s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m1.144s
```

Comment: What would be really nice is to have a `bs=auto` feature in `dd` that will detect and use the optimal bs parameter from the device.

Comment: What would be *extremely* nice is a graph of several `bs` sizes plotted against speed instead of 15 dozen code blocks in a single question. Would take less space and be *infinitely* quicker to read. A picture truly *is* worth a thoursand words.

Comment: @BigHomie - I tought about providing a graph but... there are several "scaling" problems. It would need, probably, a logaritmic scale on both axis and... while thinking to this, I tought it was not an easy (and quick) problem to solve. So I switched to the "table" version. As for the "...15 dozen code blocks", I wanted everyone had the chance to check "raw numbers", to avoid any (personal, mine) interference.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli the table is cool, please ignore my rant, I gave you an upvote for proving our superstitions anyway, and I know firsthand that fiddling with the byte size will alter the speed, I might put it into an answer as well.

Comment: Though I don't have any docs/refs, it seems likely to me that you wouldn't really see much improvement past the physical/logical block size of the device on a single drive.  `blockdev --getpbsz --getss  /dev/sda`.  I would be somewhat interested to see a similar set of tests on a RAID5/6 with a physical controller and various chuck sizes.  It seems likely that if you had a larger chuck size configured on your RAID controller, you might want to have your bs value match the chuck size.

Comment: I don't have deep knowledge of the architecture, but I think the simple answer is that when `bs < hardware block size`, the bottleneck is system call overhead, but when `bs > hardware block size` the bottleneck is data transfer. That's why the throughput plateaus when you hit that point.

Comment: I've only ever futzed with the `bs` option to make the math easier when making a swapfile (`dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=8K count=524288` for a 4G swapfile (or `8096` for systems that don't have the non-posix syntax)). The *speed* consideration is very interesting.

Comment: @user186340 you mean from the *devices*, using dd on a single device is impossible.

Comment: @warren - to get 4G you can also do `bs=8k count=512K` or `bs=1M count=4K` I don't remember powers of 2 past 65536

Comment: There is a typo in the last code header, It should be `bs=1M (offsetting the read, to avoid caching) ` instead of `bs=1k (offsetting the read, to avoid caching)`.

Comment: @Zoredache - Do you mean to stay that the block size should be the size of the physical sector size? For example, if the drive reports 4096, `dd` should be configured with `bs=4096`? What would occur if it is configured with 1MB for example?

Answer (score 38):

What you have done is only a read speed test.  if you are actually copying blocks to another device you have pauses in the reading while the other device is accepting the data you want to write,  when this happens you can hit rotational latency issues on the read device (if it's a hard disk) and so it's often significantly faster to read 1M chunks off the HDD  as you come up against rotational latency less often that way.

I know when I'm *copying* hard disks I get a faster rate by specifying `bs=1M` than by using `bs=4k` or the default.  I'm talking speed improvements of 30 to 300 percent.  There's no need to tune it for absolute best unless it's all you do every day.  but picking something better than the default can cut hours off the execution time.

When you're using it for real try a few different numbers and send the `dd` process a `SIGUSR1` signal to get it to issue a status report so you can see how it's going.

```
✗ killall -SIGUSR1 dd
1811+1 records in
1811+1 records out
1899528192 bytes (1.9 GB, 1.8 GiB) copied, 468.633 s, 4.1 MB/s
```

Comment: 2014 Macbook Pro Retina copying to USB3 stick rated at 90 MB/s write: `$ sudo dd if=~/Downloads/Qubes-R4.0-rc4-x86_64.iso of=/dev/rdisk2 status=progress` shows `6140928 bytes (6.1 MB, 5.9 MiB) copied, 23 s, 267 kB/s`. I cancelled this as it was taking too long. Now specifying the bytesize: `$ sudo dd if=~/Downloads/Qubes-R4.0-rc4-x86_64.iso of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1M status=progress` shows `4558159872 bytes (4.6 GB, 4.2 GiB) copied, 54 s, 84.4 MB/s`

Comment: If anyone interested in Mac terminal, the SIGUSR1 signal to check status is CTRL + t

Answer (score 11):

With regards to the internal hard disk, at least -- when you are reading from the device the block layer *at least* has to retrieve one sector which is 512 bytes.

So, when handling a 1 byte read you've only really read from the disk on the sector aligned byte retrieval. The remaining 511 times are served up by cache.

You can prove this as follows, in this example `sdb` is a disk of interest:

```
# grep sdb /proc/diskstats
8      16 sdb 767 713 11834 6968 13710 6808 12970792 6846477 0 76967 6853359
...
# dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/null bs=1 count=512
512+0 records in
512+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.0371715 s, 13.8 kB/s
# grep sedb /proc/diskstats
8      16 sdb 768 713 11834 6968 13710 6808 12970792 6846477 0 76967 6853359
...
```

The fourth column (which counts reads) indicates only 1 read occurred, despite the fact you requested 1 byte reads. This is expected behaviour since this device (a SATA 2 disk) has to *at a minimum* return its sector size. The kernel simply is caching the entire sector.

The biggest factor at play in these size requests is the overhead of issuing a system call for a read or write. In fact, issuing the call for < 512 is inefficient. Very large reads require less system calls at the cost of more memory being used to do it.

4096 is typically a 'safe' number for reading because:

- When reading with caching on (the default) a page is 4k. Filling up a page with < 4k  reads is more complicated than keeping the read and page size the same.
- Most filesystem block sizes are set to 4k.
- Its not a small enough number (maybe for SSDs it is now though) to cause syscall overhead but not a large enough number to consume lots of memory.