# Best way to mirror files to an external hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, hard-drive, mirroring

I have a 1 TB internal hardrive full of important files and media on a server running Ubuntu; I also have a 1 TB external hard drive that is plugged into the same server. What would be the best way to backup the internal drive to the external drive seamlessly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i'd vote Rsync if the important stuff is within a folder, I.E.

```
rsync -zuvr /home/users/me/myimportantstuff/ /media/usb/whatever/
```

For disk or partition cloning, use DD.

[Using DD for disk cloning](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning)

Comment: +1 rsync really is a good tool.  Though I might be tempted to use dirvish or rdiff-backup so that you can keep multiple versions.  Just in case you need to go back in time.

Comment: +1 on rsync.  even better through rsnapshot (which uses rsync) to have multiple versions directly accessible

Comment: Will rsync delete files on the external drive that have been removed from the internal drive?

Comment: It can if you want it to, its one of the flags.  rsync --help should list them all.