# Cloning an existing ArchLinux installation to another machine

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Is it possible to reincarnate an existing ArchLinux installation (+all existing installed software) in another machine?

I have two terminal/kiosk machines, one of them crashed a few days ago. Actually hard drive was screwed up. I might install ArchLinux from scratch then find all other software, then configure and install them.

But is it possible to take an image of working machines current state and move it to another?

Comment: It would be a better use of time to use a configuration management system and write configs in that to build your machines.

Comment: like this one? - https://github.com/CyberShadow/aconfmgr 
would you recommend any?

Comment: Maybe that would work. I'd be more apt to use one of the larger CM players, though, like ansible, salt, etc.

Comment: Did you try the `dd` option? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning & https://serverfault.com/a/268908/82440

Comment: You should restore from backups instead.

Answer (score 3):

I've done such things with rsync several times. First you should boot new machine with Arch Linux ISO and create a partition and format and mount it to /mnt. Then

`rsync -aAXxv root@SOURCEMACHINE:/ /mnt`

It excludes all mounted partitions on SOURCEMACHINE except /. You should rsync them if you have any. like:

`rsync -aAXxv root@SOURCEMACHINE:/var /mnt/var`

After that regenerate fstab and initramfs and install grub:

```
arch-chroot /mnt
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
mkinitcpio -p linux
```