# Drive cloning dd or rsync/sync via KVM

Tags: linux, rsync, disaster-recovery, data-recovery, dd

I've got a crash and the system won't boot correctly. I am getting errors like:

```
ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
ata3.00: status: { UNC }
```

What would be the best way to save the main drive to make the system boot again?

I am looking at:
[Using DD for disk cloning](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning)

I read that using DD to clone a live system is bad. But does booting in via KVM mean just as bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to do a block level copy of a drive when any of the filesystems are mounted (which also means that you can't be running the OS installed on the drive). Either boot a live CD/USB (I like [RIPLinux](http://www.tux.org/pub/people/kent-robotti/looplinux/rip/)) or connect the drive to another machine.

In terms of getting data off a dodgy drive, rather use [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) (the GNU version, sometimes called gddrescue). It won't stop as soon as it encounters a bad sector like `dd` will, and can resume copies. Make sure to specify a log file:

```
ddrescue /dev/sda /mnt/sdb1/sda.img /mnt/sdb1/sda.log
```

Comment: Is using KVM considered being mounted to the filesystems of the main drive? doesn't this CL run DD even if it does get errors? dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=32M conv=noerror,sync

Comment: @ThompsonSmith Depends how you are using KVM. If KVM is booting off an OS stored on the bad drive then that's still a problem. `noerror` will make it continue, but `ddrescue` is still better for this.

Comment: So KVM Would need to boot off a disk with a fresh OS Install? Isn't DDRescue a lot slower? I've used it once. I know data centers typically use DD. Does it depend more on the state of the drive?

Comment: @ThompsonSmith: ddrescue will go back and retry blocks that fail on the first try, so it's much better than dd for cloning flaky drives. (This also makes it slower, precisely because it doesn't just give up right away on errors.)