# dd: zero-out all the remaining unused space of a drive

Tags: linux, dd

In the second answer of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning) about disk cloning with 'dd', I read this command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/hdb/zero
```

It is supposed to write '0' in the **unused** space of drive 'hdb', however I can't find any documentation about this `/zero` tag appended to the mounted hard drive.

I understand the first part (`if=/dev/zero` is a virtual device that "creates" zeros), but what does `/mnt/hdb/zero` mean exactly? Does this really map to the unused space of a drive? Is this a typo?

I don't want to run it on my drive before being sure it won't do any harm...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The */zero*-Tag is actually a file name. The command just copies zeros from the virtual File `/dev/zero` (infinite number of zeros) into `/mnt/hdb/zero` until the disk is full, or some other error occurs.

This is why you have to remove the file `/mnt/hdb/zero` after that in order to regain the unused space.

However, a better way to fill free space with zeros (on ext2,3,4 file systems) is to use a tool called zerofree.